# 500 Error with AJAX GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, httpresponse

I am new to AJAX and I have a made a little GET call that will pull some API data from a different domain.

My question is that sometimes I get a 500 error in my `rosterPull` function, and it appears to be random so I am wondering if there is some sort of lag/propagation I am missing, or another issue within my code.

(Or is this on their end - the server I am reaching out too)

```
function teamLookUp(team) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.3/team/' + ID + '?api_key=<key>',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        },
        success: function (json) {
            //does stuff    
            rosterPull(team, CPTID);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //throws an error
        }
    });
}

function rosterPull(team, CPTID) {
    $.ajax({
        // THIS URL IS WHERE THE INSPECTOR POINTS THE 500 ERROR TOO
        url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/' + teamRosterString + '/name?api_key=<key>',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        },
        success: function (json) {
            //do stuff
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           //throws an error
        }
    });
}
```

The error that I see in Inspector and that points to the `url:https..` in function `rosterPull`.

[image]

Other than the random 500 error, everything works fine including the `rosterPull` function.

Again I am BRAND NEW to all of this, so sorry if this is a something basic.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you checked the error logs on the web server?

Comment: Yes, this is most likely on their end.

Comment: Since it's a 500 (internal server error), and it's intermittent, there may be a problem with the server itself, or a throttling issue (requests per second or per minute limit.)

Comment: Ah ok, I know that their North American server has been finicky lately, so it is probably them?

Comment: If it is intermittent it could be that you're making a bad request that causes the server-side processing to fail. The answer will be in your server's error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 is the code for an internal server error.  It's about as useful as the "check engine" light.

You'll have to check the logs on the server, or using something like fiddler to listen to the requests to get more detail on what's breaking.

Comment: Oh, is there a simple way to do this? I am current I am just running this via Debug (localhost) on Visual Studio's.

Comment: I recommend fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, it will show you all the requests and all the accompanying messages.

Comment: Quick question, is "web server" the server itself? If so I do not have any access to that.

Comment: Yes, it's the server receiving the ajax request.  Fiddler runs on the client.  So you won't need access to the server.  It's pretty straight forward to use.